# Add to cart functionality android

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm new to android. Can anyone please tell me the code for add to cart functionality.

If the press the add button in the following image

*Add button*

[image: Add button]

I need to get an increment in TextView in the following FloatingButton

*Increment needed here*

[image: Increment needed here]

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your code, to let us know, what you tried or how is build

Comment: How is your layout constructed? post your .xml in the layout folder

Comment: @Dheeraj...What have you tried??

Comment: I haven't tried it because I don't know. I've been checking for the samples in GitHub. But couldn't understand. So, I need help.

Comment: on click a button you want an increment only or save that item in cart also

Comment: Need to save that in the cart also.

Comment: your item is in list ....

Comment: every list item have one separate  add button for adding that item into cart

Comment: Yeah! And 'id' is the same for all those items in the ListView.

Comment: Start with something simple. You need to learn alot to put together a decent app. Check out Android Studio Tutorial for Beginners (Step by Step tutorial): http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS1QulWo1RIbb1cYyzZpLFCKvdYV_yJ-E

Comment: create one separate list view ....suppose cartList than on click of that add  button  cartList.add(yourMainlist.getItem(position)) you will get the clicked item ...now the item which is added in cart List are your cart item and cartList.size() will give you the no of item in cart.... you can show that in that in no of itenm in cart TEXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cart functionality in android.

1)We use [SharedPreference concept](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

2)Another Way is static ArraList

3) Sqlite database

4)[Cart functionality Example](http://androidexample.com/Use_MVC_Pattern_To_Create_Very_Basic_Shopping_Cart__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=116&aaid=138)